# setting html values using object method acts really weird

Tags: javascript, html

I have started learning JS fairly recently, and even though I am not new to coding in other languages, JS confuses me more often than not.

The 'CarFail' version of the constructor (not using JQuery) doesn't work if I create several objects (it works great when only one is created). The second 'Car' version of the constructor (using JQuery) works great.

I cannot figure out why the first constructor version fails.

I am obviously missing something trivial.

```
<div id="main"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function CarFail(x,y)
    {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;

        document.getElementById("main").innerHTML += '<img src="http://nostarch.com/images/car.png"/>';

        this.gelement=document.getElementById("main").lastChild;

        this.draw=function()
        {
            this.gelement.style.position="absolute";
            this.gelement.style.top=this.y+"px";
            this.gelement.style.left=this.x+"px";
        };
        this.draw();
    }

    function Car(x,y)
    {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;

        var carhtml = '<img src="http://nostarch.com/images/car.png"/>';

        this.gelement = $(carhtml);

        this.draw=function()
        {
            this.gelement.css({
                position: "absolute",
                left: this.x,
                top:this.y
            });
        };

        $("#main").append(this.gelement);
        this.draw();
    }

    var car1 = new Car(10,20);
    var car2 = new Car(50,90);

    car1.x=150;
    car1.draw();

</script>
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that `document.getElementById("main").lastChild` was being stored for later. I deleted my answer because that should work. What exactly goes wrong when you create multiple `CarFail`'s? I tried it and it worked fine as far as I can tell.

Comment: the two cars are drawn perfectly during their construction,  and even though the x property of car1 is changed,  its img style 'left' property doesn't change when I call the draw function.

Comment: The operation `document.getElementById("main").innerHTML +=` is modifying the inner html of the "main" div, which _recreates_ the first image tag that you add. This means that the element referenced by `car1.gelement` is no longer the same element as the one you see in the div, which is why updating and redrawing it doesn't work

Comment: To address this, use `document.createElement` and `document.getElementById("main").append` to create and append your images, rather than string manipulation on innerHTML

Comment: I Love Stack Overflow. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting `innerHTML` changes the entire document hierarchy under that element, thus any previously stored references are lost.

I suggest you instead use DOM methods

```
let img = document.createElement('img')
img.src = 'http://nostarch.com/images/car.png'
this.gelement = document.getElementById("main").appendChild(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
function CarFail(x, y) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = 'http://nostarch.com/images/car.png';

    // draw
    img.style.position = 'absolute';
    img.style.left = x + 'px';
    img.style.top = y + 'px';

    document.getElementById('main').appendChild(img);
}
```